Send email with Cloudflare/NextJS App router API
I've built a simple site using NextJS 14 and App Router which is auto deployed to Cloudflare pages via GitHub.
First part of the site the user has to enter their email address to be sent a One-Time Code via email (code stored in KV).
I'm using the standard fetch to mailchannels to send the email yet nothing seems to be coming through. I've previously had them working when built in a Worker but can't seem to get them to work when done in NextJS API routes.
I've already got the correct DNS values for the domains etc (as it previously works fine with Workers), just wondering if anyone else has been able to get it working when using NextJS API instead of a Worker.. Don't really want to spin up a Worker for the API stuff given NextJS has that out of the box.
